# Ruby Block Invocation

Tags: ruby

Two examples in Ruby:

```
def invoke_block(&block)
  block.call
end

def invoke_block(&block)
  instance_eval(&block)
end
```

Why does `instance_eval` require the `&`?

Comment: You are not passing a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does `instance_eval` require the `&`?

Because `instance_eval` accepts either a string or a block. It does not accept a Proc object (which is what name `block` is referring to, in this case). So you use operator `&` to "unpack" a proc into a block.